# How to collect data based on starting character on line?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

so I'm trying to find a more time-efficient way to "grep/search" lines which begin with a specific character/set of characters. I have a 50GB file contained with data sorted via the command `LC_ALL='C' sort -u data.txt > data_sorted.txt` Then lets say I want to find all lines which begin with **horse** I would currently do `LC_ALL='C' grep -i -E "^horse.*" data_sorted.txt`

The issue I'm facing with this command is that grep doesn't AUTOMATICALLY see (and jump to) lines which begin with **horse** instead it greps directly 0-9A-Z or whatever it does. Is there an alternate method of collating data and it jumps specifically to the first character of your search query to quicken things up.

This is kind of hard to explain, apologies for any confusion.

Comment: I don't see how that would be more beneficial. All that command is doing is grepping for ^horse in the unsorted file then after finding the results, sorting the file. Right? ;o

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use [`look(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/look.1.html). while this normally is used to search the system word list dictionary, you can specify a different file, and it does a binary search for lines matching a given prefix.

So you might try:

```
look horse data_sorted.txt
```

(Some versions of `look` might require the `-b` option to do a binary search; consult your local man page)

If you want to do a case-insensitive search like in your `grep` case, the file has to be sorted in a case-insensitive way (`sort -f`) and `look` needs the `-f` option.